# What is meaning of "TIME TO HEAD BA-" in English version of Japanese manga?

Tags: meaning, manga, english-to-japanese

What is meaning of "TIME TO HEAD BA-" in English version of Japanese manga?

Whole English context:http://mangahasu.se/onii-chan-wa-oshimai/vol-5-chapter-14-mahiro-and-a-little-adventure-c551795.html

Whole Japanese context:https://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=manga&illust_id=68003729

[image: The English version]
[image: The Japanese version]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Chocolate says, the corresponding Japanese is 「さっさと帰ってー」.

However, I think the important part here is the `ー`. The way that the the English version cuts off the word `back` suggests that the translator thinks the character was in the middle of a thought, which they interrupted.

The next frames in the manga show the character noticing a game center, and then presumably rethinking their intention to return home.

Basically, I think that the original thought was 「さっさと帰って(何かをする)」, but was interrupted by the discovery of a game center. Given that the verb `帰る` made it into the Japanese version in its entirety though, a more closely corresponding English translation might look like "Time to head back andー".

Answer (score 3):

It's 「さっさと帰って...」, so "Time to head ba(ck home)", maybe?